# virtual machines, dual booting and data disks on SSD

Tags: linux, windows, virtual-machine, ssd, samba

This is in planning, so if I've got the strategy wrong, please let me know. There are multiple questions here, but I think they all degenerate to the same answers.

The hardware is a laptop with a single SSD. I'm trying to not lose the performance of the SSD.

I plan a native dual booting Windows (plus cygwin) and Linux machine which is my BYOD and represents the development environment. I keep the codebase on a shared partition (though sometimes this is an external thunderbolt SSD) which can be natively "mounted" by whichever OS is in operation. I boot into one or the other environments depending on the task in hand. Sometime I have to develop with windows tools, but generally, Linux is my preferred development environment.

It would be ideal if I could VM the other OS and run either in either. I'm going to assume, because I've not found a sensible VM based solution, that I have get samba involved to share the code partition between VMs. Is this going to blow my SSD performance in the VM?

The client also supplies me with a VM for the target environment, usually linux. This is not often suited to development and is used for testing only. I normally keep two copies of this, one as a sandbox and one which I deploy to using the client's preferred method. I keep these VM snapshots on the shared partition.

The latter is interacted with over the network and so has no disk sharing requirements. However, it would be useful for the sandbox to be able to "mount" the code base from the natively running OS. Is this samba or nfs again, depending on the native OS?

Am I missing a trick which allows this to all work smoothly with all four environments running at once without loosing the SSD performance?

Comment: I don't understand what any of this has to do with SSD performance. Why do you think SSD performance is an issue with your setup?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Because I don't understand the implications of putting virtual network disk sharing in as a layer to disk access.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz or if there is a solution to them both using a native mounting method simultaneously

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure why you are ruling out a VM solution. VMs have these advantages: (I am copying my own answer to a somewhat similar question):

1. The machines can be working simultaneously, no need to shut down one in order to start up the other one;
2. Access times much shorter: even if you have your VM off, turning it on inside host is much faster than shutting down/booting up;
3. Ease of data sharing. Folder sharing is trivial in, for instance, VirtualBox, so that all of your data can be made simultaneously available to both systems, running concurrently. No need to worry about different filesystems, nor SAMBA configuration;
4. Ease of re-sizing of guest machine. If, after the initial installation, you should decide that you need more disk space, the task of re-sizing your virtual disk is trivial, as compared with the real task of re-sizing a non-empty partition;
5. Circumvention of access restrictions in LANs where, for instance, MAC filtering is enabled; in this case, rather than registering a new pc (the solution for the dual boot) all you have to do is enable connection of the virtual machine via NAT;
6. ease of VM control through the CLI. Basically, the whole process can be easily scripted, and even executed from remote. Try that with a dual boot.
7. Ease of relocation. With the ova format, your VM can be easily transferre to a completely different pc, running both a different OS and a different hypervisor.

And, of course, this would make the use of the client-supplied VMs also trivial.

Comment: I'm not sure I ruled out a VM solution. What I ruled out was a VM based disk sharing solution as I'd not found one that worked with SSDs.

Comment: Can you be more specific? I run several VMs on Arch and Debian pcs, all with SSIDs, without any problem.

Comment: Hmm, I'm talking about Solid State Drives.

Comment: Typo... I did men SSDs

Comment: I'm specifically looking for a disk sharing solution. When I looked into it, and certainly with vmware, there is no good way of sharing a solid state partition between two VMs.

Comment: Or are you suggesting having everything as virtual machines and no native apart from one really thin linux platform to run the VMs. Am I not going to lose a lot of hardware optimisation then? I'm going graphic processing and video editting, for instance.

Comment: I am not suggesting a thin platofrm. I am suggesting a proper install + VirtualBox guest. Sharing a folder in VB is trivial, you can actually share your whole home dir. And I have had no problems with SSDs. I run multiple servers as guests, including Tor relay, Arch/Debian/OpenBSD mirrors. Total number of simultaneous connections close to 10,000 + plus 8TB in RAID 1. Up nearly 300 days.

Comment: Well that sounds like it's just the ticket then.